# How to add live location tracking in ionic app

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, frameworks

I want to add functionality like gmap navigation into ionic hybrid application like blue dot pointer also. Previously I used geolocation API but Location is not changed when I change my position (I seem static). I want to add the live location tracking like google map. Can anyone suggest me the right way?

Comment: https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2017-02-02-realtime-google-maps-tracking-and-live-geolocation-with-javascript/

Comment: Thanks Edison, But i have one question , It is really possible only by using google api? If i dont want to use additional dependencies then what is the way to achieve that?

Comment: `watchPosition()` function from Google Maps API. It returns all information you need to change markers in your map.

Comment: @Cristiano. .. can you please suggest me some example for better understanding? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **watchPosition** and change marker on map. Something like:

```
var myMarker = null;

// get current position
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

// show current position on map
function showPosition(position) {
   myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
      map: new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map")),
      icon: 'img/icons/myicon.png'
  });
}

// watch user's position
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(watchSuccess, watchError, watchOptions);

// change marker location everytime position is updated
function watchSuccess(position) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    // set marker position
    marker.setPosition(latLng);
}
```

You can also use $cordovaGeolocation plugin. Take a look at plugin docs.

**getCurrentPosition** returns current position of Geolocation

**watchPosition** returns current position every time it changes. So, with this function, you can change the marker on map everytime with **setPosition** and pass coordinates to it.

Comment: It gives good results but it shows old marker's also after every position change, how to display only one marker(of latest position).

Comment: Thanks cristiano your suggestion solves my  issue. one correction there in your code, instead of    " marker.setPosition(latLng); "  we need to write  " "myMarker.setPosition(latLng); "

Comment: @Sudodev:- above example working correctly but can u tell me how to move map via user position?

Answer (score 0):

You can just apply to your `map` property the native method `setMyLocationEnabled(true)`.

See my example:

> > let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');
> >     this.map = this.googleMaps.create(element);
> >     this.map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

This last line will active a native current position marker.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it can not find watchSuccess, watchError, watchOptions here is my code

```js
      if (navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(watchSuccess, watchError, watchOptions)) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        map.setCenter(pos);
        that.MyLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(pos);

      }, function() {

      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    }

    directionsService.route({
    origin: this.MyLocation,
    destination: this.Destination,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
  
}
// watch user's position
// change marker location everytime position is updated
 watchSuccess(position) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    // set marker position
    marker.setPosition(latLng);
}
```